How do you add both data frame values and math operators to geom_text in R?
I'm attempting to use geom_text to create a label 'Ankle Absorption W = -0.52 - 0.13 x Hop Height'. My understanding is that I need to use %*% within expression() to output the x sign. The numbers are stored in a data frame. I'm having difficulty getting expression() to read the data frame values - it simply prints the data frame name.
Here's my current code:
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt)) + 
    geom_text( label = expression( 'Ankle Absorption W = ' 
    mtcars$hp[1],' ', mtcars$hp[2] %*% 'Hop Height' ) )

The result for the mtcars$hp[1] portion was simply printing 'mtcars$hp[1]' rather than the stored values.
I've looked at other posts and tried using bquote() and paste() within expression() but it just prints 'bquote' and 'paste'.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. I would expect a syntax error from the code you shared. Your expression looks invalid. What exactly did your bquote() attempt look like? Because that's they way you'll need to go here.

When bquote and expression aren't working for me, I go to ggtext, where we can specify components using markdown / unicode / HTML, e.g. &times; to get the unicode multiplication symbol.

@JonSpring - thank you! I think this will work well for what I need.

@MrFlick Thanks for your response! You're right, I did get a syntax error when I tried the expression today. It's odd because I didn't get an error yesterday. I wasn't having much luck with bquote. I wanted to be able to do something along the lines of ggplot2(mtcars, aes(hp, wt)) +   geom_text( label = bquote( 'Ankle Absorption W = ' ~ .(mtcars$hp[1] ) ~ .(mtcars$mpg[1] ) ~ 'Hop Height' ) ). I couldn't figure out how to add the multiplication symbol with bquote - the function is new to me. Sorry for my clunky replies. I haven't posted here before and I'm not sure how to format this well.

Here's an example using ggtext with a standard data set (with shorter variable names):
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt)) +
  ggtext::geom_richtext(aes(label = glue::glue("{hp} &times; {wt}")), 
                        fill = NA, label.color = NA)


